# how to allign two text areas in html

Tags: html, css

how to align two text areas in html.
I was trying below code

```html
<div text-align:right>
<label for="source" style="margin-right: 90px;margin-top: 500px;">Source Address: </label>
<textarea id="source" style="vertical-align:middle;"></textarea><br><br>
<label for="source" style="margin-right: 90px;margin-top: 500px;">Destination Address: </label>
<textarea id="Destination" style="vertical-align:middle;"></textarea>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please find attached screen for the example

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I have added this css in `label` tag `display: inline-block; width: 28%; margin-right: 1%;`.

```html
<div text-align:right>
  <label for="source" style="display: inline-block; width: 28%; margin-right: 1%;">Source Address: </label>
  <textarea id="source" style="vertical-align:middle;"></textarea><br><br>
  <label for="source" style="display: inline-block; width: 28%; margin-right: 1%;">Destination Address: </label>
  <textarea id="Destination" style="vertical-align:middle;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: big space between label and text area

Answer (score 1):

1) you miss style attribute in first div:

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
```

2) I use of `table-row` and `table-cell` :

```css
.myRow {
  display: table-row;
} 

label,textarea {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  padding-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: right;">

  <div class="myRow">
    <label for="source">Source Address: </label>
    <textarea id="source"></textarea>
  </div>
  
  <div class="myRow">
    <label for="source">Destination Address: </label>
    <textarea id="Destination"></textarea>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: .row is not working...coming as comment in the output

Comment: @Airerr, i fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do personally is add a class to both `label` elements and set a fixed width for that class.

For a quick fix, you can try:

```
<div text-align:right>
<label for="source" style="margin-right: 90px;margin-top: 50px; width: 150px;">Source Address: </label>
<textarea id="source" style="vertical-align:middle;"></textarea><br><br>
<label for="source" style="margin-right: 90px;margin-top: 50px; width: 150px;">Destination Address: </label>
<textarea id="Destination" style="vertical-align:middle;"></textarea>
</div>
```